How to get PowerShell to change cell value in CSV
I'm trying to make PowerShell interact with a CSV file and update it's values. There are four columns in the CSV: "Object Name", "Times Flagged", "Date Last Flagged", and "Notes" (the last one intended to be manual entry/editing only). Currently, the script gets a list of object names from a txt file, and compares them to all the values under "Object Name", and is able to figure out which objects already exist on the CSV and which do not.
What I'm currently trying to get it to do is update the existing entries by increasing the "Times Flagged" value by 1, and changing the "Date Last Flagged" to the current date. I decided to work on getting it to add "Date Last Flagged" first before figuring out "Times Flagged".
Here's my code as of right now:
   $listFile = Get-Content "\\File Path\Test List.txt"
   $csvFile = Import-Csv -Path '\\File Path\Test Report.csv'
   $Now = [datetime]::Now

   foreach($object in $listFile)
   {
      if($csvFile | Where-Object {$_.'Object Name' -eq $object}) #Updates existing entries
      {
         Where({$_.'Object Name' -eq $object}).'Date Last Flagged' = $Now
      }
      else #Adds new entries
      {
         
      }
   }

When running the script as it currently is, the host spits out error messages for each existing entry it attempts to update.

Honestly, your code makes no sense.
If, Where and the pipeline simply do not work like that.
here, have some code
$listFilePath = Resolve-Path -Path '\\File Path\Test List.txt'
$CsvFilePath = Resolve-Path -Path '\\File Path\Test Report.csv'

# added piping to where-object to filter away empty lines.
# feel free to remove it if you are sure there will not be any
$listFile = Get-Content -LiteralPath $listFilePath | Where-Object { $_ }

# because it's possible we are going to add elements, it's better to cast the array as LIST
[System.Collections.Generic.List[pscustomobject]]$csvFile = Import-Csv -LiteralPath $CsvFilePath

# evaluate forcing a specific format
$Now = [datetime]::Now

foreach ($item in $listFile) {
    # by calling a property name on a collection, 
    # you basically generate a virtual array of only that property
    # much easier to check!
    #
    # if the item exists in the virtual array
    if ($item -in $csvFile.'object name') {
        # find the index of the item in the virtual array
        # the virtual array and the collection share the same index values
        $index = $csvFile.'object name'.IndexOf($item)

        # Because everything from Csv-Import is a String:
        # Cast the property to INT and add +1
        [int]$csvfile[$index].'times flagged' += 1

        $csvfile[$index].'Date Last Flagged' = $Now
    }
    # if the item doesn't exists in the virtual array
    else {
        # create a new object and add it to the Collection
        $csvFile.Add(
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Object name'       = $item
                'Times Flagged'     = 1
                'Date Last Flagged' = $Now
                'Notes'             = [string]::Empty

            }
        )
    }
}
# export back the result to the CSV file
# -NotTypeInformation is for legacy purposes if you are using 5.1
$csvFile | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $CsvFilePath -NoTypeInformation

